# Any replacement for stfloats package

Tags: floats, packages

Is there any package like stfloats providing double column float placement

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The [CTAN summary page of `stfloats`](https://ctan.org/pkg/stfloats) explicitly states "The stfloats package provides: [...] a command that declares that double floats should be placed at the bottom (rather than the top) of a page." Therefore, please clarify, what kind of behaviour you expect and why the `stfloats` package does not work in your case. A [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) as well as a description/sketch of the expected output/behaviour would also be really useful here.

Comment: multicol can be turned off and on for floats.  One can use flowfram, but the placement is done in the preamble.  I seem to recall a package which forms the page into slices, but can never find it.